# Merging Datetime Indices With Slightly Different Dates in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

I'm trying to merge two pandas dataframes with different datetime indices. DF1 is the **quarterly** financial statements for XYZ company, DF2 is the **daily closing price** of public traded shares of XYZ stock.

The problem is the release date of the financial report doesn't always pair with the what's present for the daily closing price (presumably because the report was released on the weekend).

I need a way to fuzz the dates from DF2 so that when I merge them with DF1, the merge picks the closest date from DF2 instead of leaving a blank space for the closing price in the merge.

Currently using:

```
df1 = [['2007-12-30','$xxx,xxx'],
       ['2008-03-30','$xxx,xxx'],
       ['2008-06-28','$xxx,xxx'],
       ['2008-09-29','$xxx,xxx'],
       ['2008-12-31','$xxx,xxx']]

df2 = [['2007-12-30','$45'],
       ['2008-03-30','$40'],
       ['2008-06-27','$38'],
       ['2008-09-29','$46'],
       ['2008-12-30','$50']]

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='date')
```

RETURNS:

```
df3 = [['2007-12-30','$xxx,xxx', '$45'],
       ['2008-03-30','$xxx,xxx', '$40'],
       ['2008-06-28','$xxx,xxx', 'NaN'],
       ['2008-09-29','$xxx,xxx', '$46'],
       ['2008-12-31','$xxx,xxx', 'Nan']]
```

WANT IT TO RETURN:

```
df3 = [['2007-12-30','$xxx,xxx', '$45'],
       ['2008-03-30','$xxx,xxx', '$40'],
       ['2008-06-28','$xxx,xxx', '$38'],
       ['2008-09-29','$xxx,xxx', '$46'],
       ['2008-12-31','$xxx,xxx', '$50']]
```

**Solution:**

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='date')\ 
        .sort_index(ascending=False).fillna(method="ffill")

df3 = df3[df3.index.isin(df1.index)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fillna(method="ffill")` to get a previous value and then save only rows which date is present in df1

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='date').sort_values('date').fillna(method="ffill")
df3 = df3[df3['date'].isin(df1['date'])]
         date    xprice price
0  2007-12-30  $xxx,xxx   $45
1  2008-03-30  $xxx,xxx   $40
2  2008-06-28  $xxx,xxx   $38
3  2008-09-29  $xxx,xxx   $46
4  2008-12-31  $xxx,xxx   $50
```

Comment: I may be implementing this wrong but I don't think fillna will work. DF2 has the closing price for each day of the year so there are way more values than df1. When I use fillna it takes the closing price from when the date in DF2 last matched DF1 which would make the closing price 3 months off.

Comment: As I undestand, in the case fillna gets from prev row, and using of sort after merge results in getting a prev available date

Comment: I added a table in my question so you can see the difference in prices.

Comment: Yes that did it. I was throwing an error originally on sort_values but it was because I had already set the date as the index in df1 df2. I'll post the changes in the quesiton. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

mylist1 = [['2007-12-30','$xxx,xxx'],
       ['2008-03-30','$xxx,xxx'],
       ['2008-06-28','$xxx,xxx'],
       ['2008-09-29','$xxx,xxx'],
       ['2008-12-31','$xxx,xxx']]


mylist2 = [['2007-12-30','$45'],
       ['2008-03-30','$40'],
       ['2008-06-27','$38'],
       ['2008-09-29','$46'],
       ['2008-12-30','$50']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(mylist1,columns=['date', "value"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(mylist2,columns=['date', "value"])
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, right_index=True, left_index=True)
```